# How to get repeater to fill the width of the screen?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, border

I'm using a Repeater to create a grid but the grid doesn't fill the width of the screen. It cut offs and leaves blank spaces between the end of the repeater and the border on the right.[image]

I tried setting the last `<td>` tag to `width:100%` which did make the line go all the way across but it caused all the other columns to move over to the far left and ruined the layout.

Code:

```
<tr>
                <td style="border-left:1px solid; border-right:1px solid; height:400px" >
                    <asp:Repeater ID="rptHazDetails" runat="server">
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <table border="1">
                            <tr style="border-bottom:1px solid;">
                                 <td>
                                    UN Number, </br>
                                    Proper Shipping Name
                                </td>
                                <td style="padding:5px">
                                    Class , </br>
                                    Packing Group
                                </td>
                                <td style="padding:5px">
                                    Pieces
                                </td> 
                                <td style="padding:5px">
                                    Tunnel Code
                                </td>
                                <td style="padding:5px">
                                    Gross KG
                                </td>
                                <td style="padding:5px">
                                    Net KG
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <tr style="border-bottom:1px solid;">
                            <td style="padding:5px;">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblUNNumber" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("UnNumber") %>' /> </br>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblProper" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Packages") %>' />
                            </td>
                            <td style="padding:5px;">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblClass" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("IMOClass") %>' /> </br>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblPacking" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("IMOPage") %>' />
                            </td>
                            <td style="padding:5px;">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblPieces" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PieceBreakDown") %>' />
                            </td>
                            <td style="padding:5px;">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblTunnelCode" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TunnelCode") %>' />
                            </td>
                            <td style="padding:5px;">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblGrossWeight" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("GrossWeight","{0:0.##}") %>' />
                            </td>
                            <td style="padding:5px;">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblNetWeight" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("NetWeight","{0:0.##}") %>' />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        </table>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

I just want to border lines to reach all the across the screens and don't leave a gap.

Comment: I wanted to ask you if you have an update. Thanks Fabrizio

Answer (score 0):

I set:

```
table {
  width: 100%;
}
```

This way the table will cover the entire window. I then can choose to give each column a different width in px or %, the best way is using bootstrap classes. So include in your header

Then you can set a class for example col-md-4 for giving that column a span of 4 columns, you can also hide the column for sm screens and do other effects. Go and check

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Or ask me more informations

Fabrizio Bertoglio

Comment: I tried setting the table width to 100% but that didn't work

Comment: @user123456789 sorry, I made a mistake. You should use `table { width: 100%; }`